# statsmode ols with two-way clustered SD gives me an error with the groups

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, robust

I have a data set of bond issuance that looks like the following:

| IssuerCUSIP | NATION | Industry | Amount | IssuedPostEvent | YEAR | QUARTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | Mexico | A | 100 | 0 | 2010 | 2010Q1 |
| 000002 | China | B | 200 | 1 | 2015 | 2015Q2 |
| 000002 | China | B | 150 | 0 | 2014 | 2014Q3 |
| 000003 | China | C | 130 | 1 | 2018 | 2018Q4 |
| 000004 | Chile | C | 100 | 0 | 2012 | 2012Q1 |
| 000005 | Chile | D | 100 | 1 | 2013 | 2013Q2 |

The data is aggregated at issuer-quarter level. Each row represent newly issued corporate bond amount.
The regression context is like this: There are certain types of events that happen in each country. I am trying to see if these events will have any impact on issuing bond amounts in the US Dollar in that country. Therefore I regress a difference-in-differences equation in the following manner:
`

```
AMT ~ POSTEVENT +C(NATION)+C(INDUSTRY)*C(YEAR)+C(QUARTER)
```

`

A issuer (identified by an unique CUSIP) is nested in a country-industry group. Therefore I consider a two way clustered standard error and use the following code to get it:
`

```
MOD = smf.ols("AMT ~ POST*INCLUDE +C(NATION)+C(INDUSTRY)*C(YEAR)+C(QUARTER)", data=issueinUSD) 
RES = MOD.fit(cov_type='cluster',cov_kwds={'groups':np.asarray(pd.concat([issueinUSD['NATION'],issueinUSD['QUARTER']]))})
```

`I try to get groups for clustering with the cov_kwds specification. But I keep getting this error:`

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in fit(self, method, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
    341 
    342         if isinstance(self, OLS):
--> 343             lfit = OLSResults(
    344                 self, beta,
    345                 normalized_cov_params=self.normalized_cov_params,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in __init__(self, model, params, normalized_cov_params, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
   1605                     use_t = use_t_2
   1606                 # TODO: warn or not?
-> 1607             self.get_robustcov_results(cov_type=cov_type, use_self=True,
   1608                                        use_t=use_t, **cov_kwds)
   1609         for key in kwargs:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type, use_t, **kwargs)
   2550                     # duplicate work
   2551                     self.n_groups = n_groups = len(np.unique(groups))
...
    107     else:

<__array_function__ internals> in bincount(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: The weights and list don't have the same length.
```

`
Can anyone tell me why this error comes up.

If i only use one way cluster, it gives an estimation. But two way cluster, no.
I also don't have any NaN values in my groups.

Comment: try np.column_stack to combine the two group arrays into a 2-d group array with observation in rows and groups in the two columns

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have nans in other variables (not in the group variables, but maybe in actual Y and X variables).